# how to position google maps controls to precision?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

For precise customization how can we position de google maps controls?

This seems complicated with css since they do not have specific ids or classes.

They all have the class :

```
.gmnoprint
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the :nth-child() [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

left controls (arrow, zoom and street view)

```
 #map .gmnoprint:nth-child(7) {
    //position:absolute; --> default
    top: whatever pt !important;
 }
```

"map/satelite" buttons

```
 #map .gmnoprint:nth-child(8) {
    top: whatever pt !important;
 }
```

Comment: Beware that Internet Explorer before version 9 does not support the nth-child selector—however you can probably use a JavaScript fallback.